# HTML5 'time' tag not setting value properly

Tags: javascript, time, html

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<script>


setInterval("settime()", 1000);

function settime () {
  var dateTime = new Date();
  var hours = dateTime.getHours();
  var minutes = dateTime.getMinutes();
  var time = "";

  if (hours === 0) { 
    hours = 12;
  }

  time = (hours > 12 ? hours - 12 : hours) + ":" +
         (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes + (hours > 12 ? "PM" : "AM");

  // Doesn't work at all...
  document.getElementsByTagName('time').textContent = time;
  document.getElementsByTagName('time').innerHTML = time;


  console.log('Time set with js: ' + document.getElementsByTagName('time').textContent);

  // Works fine...
    //$('time').text(time);
}
</script>

<body>

    <time></time>

</body>
</html>
```

Why does the regular JS not work at all but the jQuery `text()` works just fine?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ColdToast/4EqxW/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a nodeList and not a single element, you have to specify which. Node lists work like arrays so doing:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].innerHTML = time;
```

works.

http://jsfiddle.net/4EqxW/3/

Comment: I think you are going to win by a nice 7 secs :)

Comment: whoa, he was here 7 secs after me, not in reverse ;-) (19:30:14Z vs. 19:30:08Z)

Comment: @Marek Sebera the date changed when i updated the answer.. bu if you check your fiddle url you will see it has a 4 and mine has a 3 because i saved it first. In anyway that is just a detail we are both right (:

Comment: time of save on jsfiddle is not important to time of posting answer here ;) but as you say, just a detail

Comment: Man I love it when I toss ppl an easy softball like this :)

Answer (score 1):

Note the `document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].` part

http://jsfiddle.net/4EqxW/4/

`getElementsbyTagName` is returning array of Nodes (NodeList) so you have to specifiy to which element you're accesing properties

Answer (score 1):

Marek Sebera and "amosrivera" answered the first part of your question (the main part)

And then to answer the second part of your question...

jQuery's "text()" method will perform the desired result on **ALL** of the elements that match your original selector (aka... every "time" element on the page).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].textContent = time;
document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].innerHTML = time;
```

Note that `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList, which is an array, not a single element. [Results of code change.](http://jsfiddle.net/4EqxW/5/)